# Not able to add library into my application?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-extension

I am trying to add the library into the Kotlin but it is not getting proper install in it.

Following error I am getting while importing the library, please check it

```
Error: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1.
Searched in the following locations:
 file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio Preview/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.1/gradle-2.3.1.pom
 file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio Preview/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.1/gradle-2.3.1.jar
 https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.1/gradle-2.3.1.pom
 https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.1/gradle-2.3.1.jar
Required by:
 project: slidingmenulib
```

I am using the following project `build.gradle`

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3-2'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha9'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And my module build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.zargow.kotlin"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation  'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-beta2'

    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    compile 'org.jetbrains.anko:anko-design:0.8.3'

    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-beta2'

}
```

I am using the library for sliding menu, please check [this](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu). I need to import this library into my kotlin project but getting error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In progect gradle file use

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://jzaccone.github.io/SlidingMenu-aar" }
    }
}
```

and in app gradle add

```
dependencies {
....
compile 'com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu:library:1.3@aar'
}
```

Comment: Thanks..It has worked for me :)...One question  is that why i am getting error on `Kotlin` to import the library..The same libraray , i have used in `Andorid studio` ,it worked but not in `Kotlin`??..Any suggestion on it??

Comment: @Ravindra Kushwaha Seems like you'r trying to add library as module but it depends on earlyest gradle build version `https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.1/gradle-2.3.1.jar Required by: project :slidingmenulib`